# How to calculate balance that can be arbitrary redefined?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a formula to calculate how much a person currently owe, while accepting adjustment values that will ignore all previous calculations (based on a code number order, since dates aren't always available), becoming the new owed value.

| Code | Name | Employee | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Loan | Jhon | $3,000 |
| 2 | Payment | Jhon | 600 |
| 3 | Payment | Jhon | 300 |
| 4 | Payment | Jhon | 200 |
| 5 | Payment | Jhon | 700 |
| 6 | Payment | Jhon | 216 |
| 7 | Adjust | Jhon | 216 |
| 8 | Loan | Jhon | 50 |
| 9 | Payment | Jhon | 100 |

This is the best formula that I came up with so far, but It has 2 flaws: It doesn't take the code order into consideration, and for some reason it's not outputting the right result:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(D:D,MATCH("Adjust",B:B,0))+SUMIF(OFFSET(B2,MATCH("Adjust",B:B,0),0),"Loan",OFFSET(D2,MATCH("Adjust",B:B,0),0))-SUMIF(OFFSET(B2,MATCH("Adjust",B:B,0),0),"Payment",OFFSET(D2,MATCH("Adjust",B:B,0),0)),SUMIF(B:B,"Loan",D:D)-SUMIF(B:B,"Payment",D:D))
```

The expected result is *166*, but the formula outputs a wrong value because for some reason it's ignoring the "Loan" value on line 8.

Comment: Can you maybe explain in super noob terms how to arrive at the expected output of `251` for the above sample dataset?!

Comment: @rockinfreakshow, Sure, sorry if it wasn't clear: The formula should output how much the person owe. If Jhon take a 3000 loan, and then pay 600, 300, 200, 700 and 216, he owes 984, because : ((3000 - (600 + 300+ 200+ 700 + 216)) is equal to 984. But after that there was a adjustment of his owed amount to 216. So now he owes 216. After that, he took another $50 loan, and paid 100, so he owes 166. And I just realized that it's not 251 haha sorry. So it should outputs 166

Comment: Are there goin' to be multiple `Adjust`s & we need to pick the last one or so... Also doesnt your current formula already give the `116` [output](https://i.imgur.com/o6yugyA.png)

Comment: Yes, there will be multiple Adjusts. And yes, the output is currently 116, but it should be 166: At row 7 he's owed amount was adjusted to 216, then he took $50, so he now owes 266, but then he paid 100, so in the end he owes 166. I don't know why is outputting 116, but I guess it's ignoring the row 8.  Regardless of that, I realized that this formula will not take in consideration any sorting of the data. For that, there should be some kind of key associated to it, like an enumerated code. But I can leave the sort implement for later

Comment: I've seen personal finance apps that fix this issue by inserting a symbolic entry with the value that when calculated alongside with all other entries, will output the right info. But I guess it would be too complicated for google sheet, probably would require appscript. So i figured this would be a easy way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=let(Σ,ifna(xmatch("Adjust",B:B,,-1),2),
       reduce(,index(D:D,Σ):index(D:D,rows(D:D)),lambda(a,c,a+if(offset(c,,-2)="Payment",-1,1)*c)))
```

- Added 2 `Adjust` scenarios to check on if its picking up the last one

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It works! And that's a lot more complicated than I've anticipated. What if you want to filter by an employee's name, in order to get only he's owed amount?

Comment: try replacing ***lambda*** part of the above formula with `lambda(a,c,a+if(offset(c,,-1)="Jhon",if(offset(c,,-2)="Payment",-1,1)*c,))` [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/bNIuAlU.png)

Comment: For some reason it returns 0 : `=let(Σ,ifna(xmatch("Adjust",B:B,,-1),2),reduce(,index(D:D,Σ):index(D:D,rows(D:D)),lambda(a,c,a+if(offset(c,,-1)="Jhon",if(offset(c,,-2)="Payment",-1,1)*c,))))`